# node.js: can't install compress-buffer

Tags: node.js

I tried to install compress-buffer with

```
npm install compress-buffer
```

I got the error shown in the screenshot pasted below. I looked at the npm-debug.log but I couldn't find any useful information.

http://bit.ly/19dgTcb

How can I fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with developing on Windows, but I did want to point out this error in the screenshot that lead to a few promising Google search results: "Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Windows 7 SDK and VS C++ Express 2010 (or appropriate SDK/VS C++ version for your Windows) along with python 2.7 to build/install packages on Windows.